# mysql joining column from another table on different conditions

Tags: mysql, join, case

I have a 'pricelist' table. I am trying to join one column, new_rate, from another table called 'rate_cycles' and it should be based on certain conditions. I am having troubles creating such a query.
Pricelist table contain prefixes, here are the samples from both tables. I am joining 'new_rate' from cycles if a pair country + region from pricelist matches.

If (in cycles table) prefix is null and notified 0 i need to join 'new_rate' from that row. If it is notified (notified=1) i need to find, if exists, next row where notified is 0. If in that row the prefix is null then i join new_rate from that row, but if prefix is not null then for new_rate value i need the last row where prefix is null and notified is 1 (if exists, if not then null).

How could I achieve this? Thanks.

Pricelist table

```
+----+--------------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
| id | pricelist_id | country | region       | prefix  | is_mobile | is_fixed | is_custom | currency | rate   | last_updated        | has_rate_cycle |
+----+--------------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
|  2 |            1 | Albania | Fixed ALBTEL | 3554249 |         0 |        0 |         0 | USD      | 0.0000 | 2014-09-23 09:48:00 |              1 |
|  3 |            1 | Albania | Fixed ALBTEL | 3554250 |         0 |        0 |         0 | USD      | 0.0000 | 2014-09-23 09:48:00 |              1 |
|  4 |            1 | Albania | Fixed ALBTEL | 3554251 |         0 |        0 |         0 | USD      | 0.0000 | 2014-09-23 09:48:00 |              1 |
|  5 |            1 | Albania | Fixed ALBTEL | 3554252 |         0 |        0 |         0 | USD      | 0.0000 | 2014-09-23 09:48:00 |              1 |
+----+--------------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
```

Cycles table

```
+----+------------+---------+--------------+----------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------+---------+
| id | carrier_id | country | region       | new_rate | activation_date     | update_status | prefix  | notified | grouped |
+----+------------+---------+--------------+----------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------+---------+
|  1 |         15 | Albania | Fixed ALBTEL |   1.0000 | 2014-09-30 03:48:00 | NEW           | NULL    |        0 |       0 |
|  2 |         15 | Albania | Fixed ALBTEL |   2.0000 | 2014-10-01 03:48:00 | BLOCKED       | 3554250 |        0 |       0 |
|  3 |         15 | Albania | Fixed ALBTEL |   3.0000 | 2014-10-02 03:48:00 | DECREASE      | NULL    |        0 |       0 |
|  4 |         15 | Albania | Fixed ALBTEL |   4.0000 | 2014-10-03 03:48:00 | NEW           | 3554250 |        0 |       0 |
+----+------------+---------+--------------+----------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry, Thanks, I will. I will create a schema at sqlfiddle.

Comment: Don't forget that this course of action has two steps!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/ee223/1    here is the fiddle, what do you mean please by the second step ?

Answer (score 0):

It was a tough query and managed to make it to do what i need. It'll be great if it could be simplified a little bit. I am sharing my solution.

```
SELECT p.id,p.country, p.region, p.prefix, p.currency, p.rate,

    (SELECT CASE WHEN notified = 0

    THEN    (SELECT CASE WHEN prefix IS NULL
        THEN new_rate
        ELSE    (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(new_rate)>0
                THEN (SELECT new_rate FROM pricelist_rates_cycle WHERE country=p.country and region=p.region and notified=1 and prefix is null order by DATE(activation_date) DESC LIMIT 1)
                ELSE NULL
                END
                FROM pricelist_rates_cycle WHERE country=p.country and region=p.region and notified=1 and prefix is null
                )
        END
        FROM pricelist_rates_cycle WHERE country=p.country and region=p.region and notified=0 LIMIT 1)

    ELSE (
            SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(new_rate)>0
            THEN IF( prefix is null, new_rate,
                    (SELECT new_rate FROM pricelist_rates_cycle WHERE country=p.country and region=p.region and notified=1 and prefix is null order by DATE(activation_date) DESC LIMIT 1)
                    )
            ELSE (SELECT new_rate FROM pricelist_rates_cycle WHERE country=p.country and region=p.region and notified=1 and prefix is null order by DATE(activation_date) DESC LIMIT 1)
            END
            FROM pricelist_rates_cycle WHERE country=p.country and region=p.region and notified=0
         )
    END
    FROM pricelist_rates_cycle WHERE country=p.country and region=p.region LIMIT 1) AS new_rate

FROM pricelist_15 AS p ORDER BY country, region ASC
```